# Cannot see USB drives

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I inserted a USB drive to my computer that worked previously but now it does not.

When USB is connected and I type `lsusb`:

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c326 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1038:1710 SteelSeries ApS 
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade is the one I connected.
When I type `lsblk` with USB connected:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 297.1G  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   450M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  18.6G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0  79.2G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdc2   8:34   0 916.3G  0 part /mnt/sdc2
└─sdc5   8:37   0  15.3G  0 part [SWAP]
```

And without:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 297.1G  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   450M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  18.6G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0  79.2G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdc2   8:34   0 916.3G  0 part /mnt/sdc2
└─sdc5   8:37   0  15.3G  0 part [SWAP]
```

For some reason this devise does not show up here. I cannot even mount it as I don't know it's name. Why is it that the USB is detected by `lsusb` but from there on it's unusable? This problem persists with other USB drives also.

Output of command `dmesg`:

```
[787224.169426] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[787224.169428] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
[787224.169721] serial 00:06: disabled
[787224.169723] serial 00:06: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[787224.986598] PM: suspend of devices complete after 842.292 msecs
[787224.987392] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.790 msecs
[787224.988147] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[787224.988284] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[787224.988524] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[787224.988531] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[787224.999643] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 12.246 msecs
[787225.000406] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[787225.001477] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[787225.001508] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[787225.020921] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[787225.040830] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[787225.057465] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[787225.059560] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[787225.059592] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[787225.061557] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[787225.061587] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[787225.061587] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[787225.064835]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[787225.064964] CPU1 is up
[787225.064979] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[787225.068225]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[787225.068373] CPU2 is up
[787225.068384] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[787225.071642]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[787225.071799] CPU3 is up
[787225.074154] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[787225.074766] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[787225.078139] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[787225.078142] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[787225.088146] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 13.597 msecs
[787225.088427] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.270 msecs
[787225.088597] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[787225.089222] serial 00:06: activated
[787225.094720] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[787225.101510] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[787225.101514] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[787225.102108] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Starting disk
[787225.137971] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[787225.323966] nct6775: Enabling hardware monitor logical device mappings.
[787225.424592] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[787225.443875] PM: resume of devices complete after 355.458 msecs
[787225.444127] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[787225.444128] Restarting tasks ... 
[787225.444261] pci_bus 0000:05: Allocating resources
[787225.444277] pci 0000:04:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[787225.444281] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[787225.444288] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0400000-0xe05fffff]
[787225.444294] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0600000-0xe07fffff 64bit pref]
[787225.451684] done.
[787225.485806] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[787225.486145] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[787225.486208] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[787225.514712] ata3.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[787226.917974] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[787226.919650] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[787226.993504] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[787227.033765] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[787227.033840] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[787229.970041] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[787229.970050] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[787230.357881] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[787230.359507] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[807934.442320] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[807934.533564] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[807934.793540] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.022 seconds) done.
[807934.816503] Double checking all user space processes after OOM killer disable... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) 
[807934.816554] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[807934.817692] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[807934.817706] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[807934.823191] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[807934.823230] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[807934.823264] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[807934.823348] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[807934.823785] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[807934.824250] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
[807934.843200] serial 00:06: disabled
[807934.843203] serial 00:06: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[807935.627181] PM: suspend of devices complete after 809.381 msecs
[807935.628006] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.821 msecs
[807935.628795] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[807935.628869] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[807935.629104] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[807935.629181] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[807935.639839] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 11.829 msecs
[807935.640602] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[807935.641615] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[807935.641641] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[807935.661122] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[807935.680990] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[807935.701058] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[807935.703176] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[807935.703208] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[807935.705162] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[807935.705191] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[807935.705192] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[807935.708441]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[807935.708573] CPU1 is up
[807935.708586] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[807935.711931]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[807935.712074] CPU2 is up
[807935.712086] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[807935.715339]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[807935.715499] CPU3 is up
[807935.717855] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[807935.721665] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[807935.721667] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[807935.721728] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[807935.731670] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 13.405 msecs
[807935.731931] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.249 msecs
[807935.732050] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[807935.732057] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[807935.732641] serial 00:06: activated
[807935.748969] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[807935.748982] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[807935.748987] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Starting disk
[807935.772366] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[807935.968400] nct6775: Enabling hardware monitor logical device mappings.
[807935.968765] PM: resume of devices complete after 236.839 msecs
[807935.968983] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[807935.968983] Restarting tasks ... 
[807935.969102] pci_bus 0000:05: Allocating resources
[807935.969117] pci 0000:04:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[807935.969120] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[807935.969126] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0400000-0xe05fffff]
[807935.969130] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0600000-0xe07fffff 64bit pref]
[807935.988853] done.
[807936.068268] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[807936.129057] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[807936.129785] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[807936.129858] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[807936.164891] ata3.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[807937.568192] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[807937.569970] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[807937.690378] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[807937.730652] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[807937.730719] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[807940.665189] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[807940.665198] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[807940.984723] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[807940.986369] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[849268.721533] usb 2-11: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[849349.796133] usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 6
[849366.581882] usb 2-11: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[849551.846331] usb 2-12: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[849578.507902] usb 2-12: USB disconnect, device number 8
[849579.448611] usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 7
[849628.783983] usb 2-12: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[849665.749645] usb 2-12: USB disconnect, device number 9
[849700.301519] usb 2-9: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[849733.955910] usb 2-9: USB disconnect, device number 10
[850188.593086] usb 2-11: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[850190.297604] usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 11
[851843.491757] usb 2-12: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[851866.698670] usb 2-12: USB disconnect, device number 12
[858312.400274] usb 2-12: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[858339.395681] usb 2-12: USB disconnect, device number 13
[871889.140104] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[871889.196851] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[871889.444402] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.024 seconds) done.
[871889.468444] Double checking all user space processes after OOM killer disable... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) 
[871889.468496] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
[871889.469447] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[871889.469461] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[871889.478366] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[871889.478479] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[871889.478506] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[871889.478604] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[871889.478606] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[871889.479276] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
[871889.494998] serial 00:06: disabled
[871889.495001] serial 00:06: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[871890.296371] PM: suspend of devices complete after 826.821 msecs
[871890.296799] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.426 msecs
[871890.297290] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[871890.297345] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[871890.297491] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[871890.297493] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[871890.309418] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 12.617 msecs
[871890.309641] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[871890.310068] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[871890.310084] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[871890.330521] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[871890.350508] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[871890.370483] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[871890.371665] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[871890.371697] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[871890.373637] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[871890.373666] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[871890.373667] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[871890.376914]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[871890.377049] CPU1 is up
[871890.377062] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[871890.380311]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[871890.380456] CPU2 is up
[871890.380470] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[871890.383730]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[871890.383896] CPU3 is up
[871890.386132] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[871890.387250] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[871890.387288] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[871890.387353] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[871890.397295] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 10.793 msecs
[871890.397570] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.264 msecs
[871890.397716] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[871890.398339] serial 00:06: activated
[871890.402800] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[871890.421880] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[871890.421902] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[871890.421903] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Starting disk
[871890.443459] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[871890.633101] nct6775: Enabling hardware monitor logical device mappings.
[871890.633456] PM: resume of devices complete after 235.892 msecs
[871890.633620] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[871890.633621] Restarting tasks ... 
[871890.633734] pci_bus 0000:05: Allocating resources
[871890.633748] pci 0000:04:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[871890.633751] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[871890.633757] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0400000-0xe05fffff]
[871890.633762] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0600000-0xe07fffff 64bit pref]
[871890.640593] done.
[871890.730953] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[871890.790224] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[871890.790571] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[871890.790633] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[871890.823846] ata3.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[871892.330465] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[871892.332173] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[871893.359565] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[871895.753672] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[871895.755329] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[871896.330417] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[871896.373056] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[871896.373072] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[871896.373126] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[871900.038838] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[871900.038846] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[929327.478586] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[929327.566195] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[929327.859157] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[929327.860992] Double checking all user space processes after OOM killer disable... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) 
[929327.861042] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
[929327.861789] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[929327.861803] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[929327.867286] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[929327.867333] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[929327.867356] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[929327.867445] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[929327.867470] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
[929327.868029] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[929327.887313] serial 00:06: disabled
[929327.887316] serial 00:06: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[929328.671728] PM: suspend of devices complete after 809.829 msecs
[929328.672572] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.840 msecs
[929328.673338] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[929328.673493] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[929328.673736] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[929328.673755] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[929328.685144] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 12.569 msecs
[929328.685907] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[929328.686956] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[929328.686987] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[929328.699791] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[929328.719640] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[929328.736317] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[929328.738445] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[929328.738476] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[929328.740425] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[929328.740454] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[929328.740455] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[929328.743702]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[929328.743835] CPU1 is up
[929328.743848] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[929328.747095]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[929328.747239] CPU2 is up
[929328.747253] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[929328.750511]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[929328.750665] CPU3 is up
[929328.753019] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[929328.753589] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[929328.756965] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[929328.756976] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[929328.766979] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 13.570 msecs
[929328.767265] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.275 msecs
[929328.767431] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[929328.768070] serial 00:06: activated
[929328.773575] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[929328.791210] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[929328.791211] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[929328.791214] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Starting disk
[929328.817049] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[929329.003337] nct6775: Enabling hardware monitor logical device mappings.
[929329.003742] PM: resume of devices complete after 236.481 msecs
[929329.003925] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[929329.003926] Restarting tasks ... 
[929329.004045] pci_bus 0000:05: Allocating resources
[929329.004060] pci 0000:04:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[929329.004063] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[929329.004069] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0400000-0xe05fffff]
[929329.004074] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0600000-0xe07fffff 64bit pref]
[929329.017574] done.
[929329.110131] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[929329.170818] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[929329.171158] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[929329.171219] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[929329.200179] ata3.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[929330.444415] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[929330.485944] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[929330.486002] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[929330.666823] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[929330.668553] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[929333.402667] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[929333.402676] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[929334.040056] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[929334.041695] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[938318.199871] usb 2-11: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[938335.339684] usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 14
[938342.015747] usb 2-11: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[938350.955846] usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 15
[940181.276041] usb 2-11: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[940239.472301] usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 16
[940247.920564] usb 2-11: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[940406.777644] usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 17
[940425.748122] usb 2-11: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[960051.496275] usb 2-11: USB disconnect, device number 18
[981187.907277] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[981187.959464] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[981188.265763] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[981188.267625] Double checking all user space processes after OOM killer disable... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) 
[981188.267680] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
[981188.268674] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[981188.268689] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[981188.271503] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[981188.272738] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
[981188.294183] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[981188.294225] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[981188.294295] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[981188.294311] serial 00:06: disabled
[981188.294312] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[981188.294314] serial 00:06: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[981189.082047] PM: suspend of devices complete after 813.268 msecs
[981189.082496] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.446 msecs
[981189.083338] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[981189.083479] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[981189.083762] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[981189.083768] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[981189.095355] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 12.855 msecs
[981189.095980] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[981189.096840] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[981189.096867] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[981189.116599] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[981189.133214] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[981189.156577] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[981189.158716] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[981189.158748] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[981189.160718] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[981189.160747] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[981189.160748] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[981189.163992]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[981189.164129] CPU1 is up
[981189.164142] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[981189.167489]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[981189.167636] CPU2 is up
[981189.167648] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[981189.170904]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[981189.171063] CPU3 is up
[981189.173418] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[981189.177183] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[981189.177195] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[981189.177229] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[981189.187191] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 13.364 msecs
[981189.187464] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.261 msecs
[981189.187597] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[981189.188212] serial 00:06: activated
[981189.190854] r8169 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[981189.211032] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[981189.211367] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[981189.211368] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Starting disk
[981189.230570] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[981189.424485] nct6775: Enabling hardware monitor logical device mappings.
[981189.424850] PM: resume of devices complete after 237.391 msecs
[981189.425059] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[981189.425060] Restarting tasks ... 
[981189.425225] pci_bus 0000:05: Allocating resources
[981189.425241] pci 0000:04:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[981189.425244] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[981189.425250] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0400000-0xe05fffff]
[981189.425254] pci 0000:04:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xe0600000-0xe07fffff 64bit pref]
[981189.433089] done.
[981189.520547] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[981189.581393] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[981189.581753] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[981189.581813] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[981189.613751] ata3.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[981191.110080] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[981191.127005] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[981191.128806] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[981191.149506] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[981191.149577] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[981194.139381] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[981194.139390] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[981194.460244] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[981194.461887] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[989800.436514] usb 2-12: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[989916.221535] usb 2-12: USB disconnect, device number 19
[1022034.107053] usb 2-12: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Remove your USB stick, then run `dmesg -c`, then insert your USB stick and run `dmesg` again and post the output of the latter.

Comment: @Thomas The output is huge, pasted the last bit.

Comment: @Kaspar There is http://pastebin.com for that.

Comment: Try to reboot your PC, reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188178

Comment: Wow, that was actually it. Had not rebooted for months already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reboot your PC when similar case happen, as stated [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1464682#p1464682) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404669/broken-usb-drive-not-given-a-name-with-lsblk#comment522913_406383). It might because of kernel update require reboot to make usb works.